# Using replaceOne() method with Java driver and MongoDB seems to not be updating an existing document

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB, and I'm having an issue re-persisting an object to the database. For simplicity sake, my current process is:

1. Pull the object out
2. Make some unidentified changes to it
3. Replace the existing item in the database (as opposed to updating a property)

My code to save the object looks like:

```
Document bson = Documents.create(player.toJSON());
System.out.println("Saving: " + bson);
UpdateResult updateResult = Mongos.db().getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).replaceOne(Filters.eq("_id", player.getId()), bson);
System.out.println("Upserted: " + updateResult.getUpsertedId());
System.out.println("Updated: " + updateResult.getModifiedCount());
System.out.println("Result: " + getOrCreatePlayer(player.getUsername()).toJSON());
```

The `getOrCreatePlayer()` simply does a `username`-based lookup, and converts the `Document` into the appropriate model object. If I `count()` the collection, I do have **one** object as expected, and the fact that querying for an object by username returns a Document with the same `_id` property suggests I'm not accidentally just returning a new instance (and ignoring the returned `Bson`).

But my output looks like:

```
Saving: Document{{hp=30, x=0, y=0, _id=55d27cff76da4319acb7d982, exp=0, inTent=false, username=craig, ap=30}}
Upserted: null
Updated: 0
Result: {"hp":30,"x":0,"y":0,"_id":"55d27cff76da4319acb7d982","exp":0,"inTent":true,"username":"craig","ap":30}
```

The most immediate sign of failure is the fact that `inTent` is not persisted. I didn't find it mentioned in the docs whether `getModifiedCount()` should be non-zero for a *replace* scenario, so I'm not sure if that's a second clue or not.

I have unit tests around the object's ability to serialize/load itself from a JSON array, so I'm confident that I'm not "losing" properties at the Java layer.

If I `count()` the collection, the object is indeed there.

Am I using `replaceOne()` properly?

Comment: What this means is that the query portion did not match. Check your `player.getId()` to see that it is actually something that should match and also that you have the right `COLLECTION_NAME` variable as well. So the `_id` needs to be returned as an `ObjectId` type for it to be valid for query here as well.

Comment: @BlakesSeven That worked - if you add as an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Though I like "free rep" as in "free beer" as much as anyone, this really seems like an internal debugging issue and as such the question and "answer" itself is not going to be very likely to help others. Hence why it was just a comment in the first place. Q&A resource here.